# async / await передача Task

Tags: c#, async-await

Есть функция

```
public Task DoAny()
{

}
```

В которой я должен просто выполнить другую асинхронную функцию (ну плюс сопутствующий код, не требующий асинхронности)

Вопрос, должен ли я сделать так

```
public async Task DoAny()
{
    await OtherFuncAsync();
}
```

или же достаточно будет этого

```
public Task DoAny()
{
    return OtherFuncAsync();
}
```

Comment: сопутствующий код, как я понимаю, до вызова OtherFuncAsync должен завершиться?

Comment: да, внутри функции async требуется await, а чтобы запустить вашу функцию нужно написать `Task.Run(DoAny);` и если требубуется то подождать `var tsk = Task.Run(DoAny); tsk.Wait();`

Comment: Если хочется ловить исключения - то нужен await. Если исключения будет ловить вызывающий код - await не нужен.

Comment: @4per функция же возвращает Task. Не обязан код завершаться. Подождёт вызывающий код, если надо.

Comment: @Monk я про то, что тема `сопутствующего кода` не раскрыта. Куда его хочет разместить автор и как он должен работать относительно задачи.

Comment: @4per а это имеет значение? Можете привести случаи, когда это может иметь значение?